# How to modify index keys using array_map() in PHP

Tags: php

I want to come up with `$desired_output` from given `$data` array below using **array_map()** or any PHP ***array_**** built-in function. Any idea how?

```
$data = array(
  'posted_name' => 'John Doe',
  'posted_age'  => '30',
);

$desired_output = array(
  'name' => 'John Doe',
  'age'  => '30',
);
```

I tried below but the result is an array of arrays:

```
$desired_output  = array_map(
    function($keys, $vals)
        {
            $new[substr($keys, strlen('posted_'))] = $vals;
            return $new;
    },
    array_keys($data),
    $data
);

print_r($desired_output );

/**
* Array (
  [0] => Array ( [name] => John Doe )
  [1] => Array ( [age] => 30 )
)
*/
```

Comment: array_map does a build in loop. the process is the same.

Comment: Iterating over array is __always__ done via a loop. The thing is that loop is hidden under the hood and you won't see it. But it is stll a loop.

Comment: `array_keys` to get the keys, map or walk those to change the key names, and splice together with `array_values` again using `array_combine` …? Sounds like a lot of effort to “avoid” a simple, self-written loop IMHO.

Comment: @CBroe but that's how JavaScript is doing it nowadays! It's more _functional™️_ ! Would you dare to deny this wonderful trend? 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about the following:

```
$desired_output = array();
array_walk(
    $data,
    function(&$val, $key) use (&$desired_output)
    {
      $len = strlen('posted_');
      if (substr($key, 0, $len) == "posted_") {
        $key = substr($key, $len);
      }
      $desired_output[$key] = $val;
    }
);

print_r($desired_output);
```

Changes:

- Using `array_walk` instead of `array_map` since _map cannot handle keys
- Creating an empty array to build the result in
- Using that array in the scope of the lambda function
- Replacing the "posted_" only if it exists in the key

Output:

```
$ php -f ~/tmp/so2.php

Array
(
    [name] => John Doe
    [age] => 30
)
```

Comment: I can't figure out why the `$val` argument is used by-reference (`&`) instead of by-value. Is it simply to not duplicate the array? Couldn't the `&` be removed if $val is always an object (aka already a reference).